# Find friends and create a users array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, social-networking

I have a basic social network.
I'm trying to create a friends method that returns an array of users. Some `user :ids` are in the `:user_id` attribute and some are in the `:friend_id` attribute. I don't want to return the `current_user.id`. I only want to return the `:name`, `:id` and `:uid` attributes. I don't know where to go from here.

I hope I simplified enough, please tell me if my question is lacking information.

Thank you!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, :conditions => {:accepted => true}
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id", :conditions => {:accepted => true}

  attr_accessible :name, :oauth_expires_at, :oauth_token, :provider, :uid

  def friends
    friendships.preload(:friend) + inverse_friendships.preload(:user)
  end
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
  attr_accessible :accepted, :friend_id, :user_id, :friend
end
```

Comment: Questions is somewhat unclear, what are the columns in your models?

Comment: Sorry if it was a little unclear. I updated it. Do you need more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
class User
  ...
  def friends
    friendships.map { |f| [f.name, f.id, f.uid] }
  end

end
```

Comment: Almost.... Instead of mapping the friendships I need to map the users of the friendships. Sorry perhaps my question wasn't clear enough. BUT your answer helped me find the answer because your approach was correct! answer is:     friendships.preload(:friend).map { |f| [f.friend.name, f.friend.id, f.friend.uid] } + inverse_friendships.preload(:user).map { |f| [f.user.name, f.user.id, f.user.uid] }  . All in one line. So if you change your answer to that i'll mark it correct for future coders to easily find. Thanks!!

Comment: Is there a way to show the attributes too? The array comes out as raw data that when called in the view it doesn't understand.